# Heegaard splitting of maps between 3-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ and $M'$ be closed oriented connected 3-manfolds and let $f : M \to M'$ be a continuous map.  Do there exist Heegaard splittings $M = H_1 \cup H_2$ and $M' = H_1' \cup H_2'$ and a map $f'$ homotopic to $f$ so that $f'$ preserves the Heegaard splittings in the sense that $f'(H_1) \subset H_1'$ and $f'(H_2) \subset H_2'$?

Let $\Sigma = H_1 \cap H_2$ and $\Sigma' = H_1' \cap H_2'$.  Note that by naturality of Mayer-Vietoris, the degree of $f'$ will have to equal the degree of $f'|_\Sigma : \Sigma \to \Sigma'$ which gives some restriction on the possible Heegaard splittings.

I believe this should not be true for $\deg(f) >1$ but I can not seem to find an obstruction.

Thanks!

Comment: This can definitely happen for maps of degree greater than 1.  In particular, it holds whenever $f$ is a covering map.  Just choose triangulations of $M$ and $M'$ such that $f$ is simplicial.  This implies that $f$ takes a tubular neighborhood of the $1$-skeleton of $M$ to a tubular neighborhood of the $1$-skeleton of $M'$.  These tubular neighborhoods (together with their complements) form Heegaard splittings of these manifolds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Waldhausen, Friedhelm*, On mappings of handlebodies and of Heegaard splittings, Topology of Manifolds, Proc. Univ. Georgia 1969, 205-211 (1971). [ZBL0282.57003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0282.57003).  [Bielefeld](https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/download/1782175/2313705).

See this paper of Waldhausen, which discusses the
case of degree 1 maps. However, in the proof of Theorem 2.1 in his paper, he sketches a proof that a map between 3-manifolds may be homotoped to preserve Heegaard splittings (the details are not given, but it seems clear that the hypothesis of degree 1 is not used in this part of the theorem). He seems to think this is "well-known", but doesn't give a reference.